# Put div in bottom of container wiht dynamic height of content-wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have a css issue.

I have two "columns" where each column contains dynamic content + images at the bottom of each column.[image: Web design]

I want these blocks of images to be in the bottom of each column. I could use `position:absolute` and set a height of each column but I'm looking for a way to achieve this without using a specified height on the columns.

The html is something like

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="content">
         {text content / dynamic }
        <div class="grid"> <!-- image blocks -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
         {text content / dynamic }
        <div class="grid"> <!-- image blocks -->
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you truely, you want to align-bottom of container's both right and left side. You can do use display:flex, give a

```
 <div class="wrapper" style="display:flex; width:100%; height:auto; justify- 
  content:flex-start; align-items:center; "></>
```

Write your other styling codes, align-items helps you to your content containers align  center vertically.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this! (test it :-))

Comment: I was basically looking for align-items:flex-end; You pointed me in right direction! Thx!